# Test Series for Stationary Process

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, gdp

### I want to apply grangers' Test between GSDP and Electricity production in the state. The state is a newly formed in the year 2000 and hence I have only 13 data points, as mentioned below

### Year     |   GSDP

### 2000-01  |   29539

### 01 to 02 |  32493

### 02 to 03 |  38802

### 03 to 04 |  47862

### 04 to 05 |  53381

### 05 to 06 |  66875

### 06 to 07 |  80255

### 07 to 08 |  96972

### 08 to 09 |  99364

### 09 to 10 |  119420

### 10 to 11 |  144382

### 11 to 12 |  163461

### 12 to 13 |  185060

The test yields that it is not a stationary process. Kpss test yields that it is not a trend stationary process. Hence a the second popular choice comes to be difference stationary process. (Transformation of data yields the same result).

The question is how to convert this process to stationary process ?. Is it advisable to apply Grangers' Test using this limited number of data points?. If not what other methodology I can adopt for the same.

Comment: Your series is too short to give any meaningful results. With so few observations the series will most likely not look very mean reverting, hence a non-stationary process. I would get some new data.